# How to record video apps for the AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store

How to record a video of the application for the AppStore?

[Instructions from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/imovie/) does not help because iTunes Connect requires specific resolution:

[image: specific resolution]

And this resolution is not in export in QuickTime Player:
[image: QuickTime Player]

not in share in iMovie:

[image: iMovie]

*"To export the final video, click Share in the toolbar, then choose App Preview"*

There is no app preview item menu.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Use iMovie. It can share as app review

Comment: @E.Coms my last screenshot is iMove share. I don't see the format App Preview. There is "iTunes" menu item: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1erlipraxylijk/2019-02-02_20-10-47.png?dl=0, but this is not the format that is suitable for the app store: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxevofhlsxa1nmg/2019-02-02_20-11-19.png?dl=0

Comment: You need to new app preview. Then after editing you can share app preview.

Comment: @E.Coms Thank you! I found it (File - New App Preview in iMovie).

Comment: You are welcome